# How to convert PNG to SVG in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, html5-canvas

I want to convert png, base64 to SVG

therefore I can delete a specific part of the image which is only possible in SVG.

Basically I want to achieve erase functionality by deleting a path from SVG

I've tried this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var svg = canvas.toDataURL('svg', 1.0);
```

But I guess there is no argument for SVG on canvas.

Do we have any method to convert?

Comment: I'm having troubling understanding what you want to achieve; can you elaborate it further with a specific example?

Comment: I wrote everything in short.
I want to delete specific part of the image which I can do it in SVG by deleting a path

Comment: I can double-click a word to select it in a text editor. Pressing space, delete or backspace removes it. But if I've got a photograph of someone's handwriting, that seems like a convoluted way of going about the task of removing content. Most people would simply put a black (or other suitable colour) rectangle over the unsuitable part of the image. Yes, it's very easy to remove a word from text when it's typed instead of photographed. So to is it quite easy to remove a picture element when using svg. Problem is though, you're not.

Comment: @enhzflep - agree in this case what we should use?

Comment: @HidaytRahman - either an SVG as the source image or a pixel-editor based approach. Is this an operation you expect to be able to perform on lots of images, or is it just a single image that needs changing, whether it be once or often?

Comment: @enhzflep - yes there will be the single image for one time

Comment: @HidaytRahman - well then, I'd just edit the picture in your favourite image-editor, save it and be done with it then. No use spending an hour to save a minute...

Answer (score 3):

PNG is a raster format... you end up with a grid of pixels.  SVG is a vector format... effectively commands to draw shapes and paths with certain styles.

They are inherently incompatible.  You cannot convert from a PNG to an SVG.  (Well, not usefully.  I suppose you could draw a rectangle for each pixel, but why would you?  The size would be huge.)

Comment: Basically I want to achieve a feature to delete a specific part of the image like rubber. Where I can erase by mouseover

Comment: In SVG you can delete specific path by clicking on that

Comment: @HidaytRahman Alright then, I'm not sure what this has to do with PNG.  You understand the differences between the formats, yes?

Comment: @HidaytRahman If I want to bake a cake, I can follow the recipe to bake that cake.  If I want to change that recipe, perhaps to add some more vanilla, I have to do that at the beginning and change the recipe.  I can't very well add vanilla to the cake after it's already been baked.

Comment: I don't find your comment helpful, if you don't know then you should not make it complex.
and yes we can convert png to SVG, this is something I was looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/potrace

Comment: @HidaytRahman Re-tracing the image is *not* simple conversion.  That's different entirely.  If you were looking for something like that, you should have added it to your question.

Comment: But still, it is doing the job

Comment: I have asked with the requirement " delete a specific part of the image which is only possible in SVG." you missed this. and after your answer, I did google a lot on SVG conversion possibilities and got this library.

Comment: @HidaytRahman Oh, I read that.  I didn't miss it.  I assumed you wanted to drop or make a section transparent, etc.  I also guessed that maybe you wanted SVG functionality, but pointed out anyway that a direct conversion is not possible and explained why.  But, whatever, I really couldn't care less what you think about the answer.  I'm sorry I took the time to explain to you the differences between the formats.

Comment: It's my pleasure you explained and given me your valuable time to answer it, however, the main problem is to achieve functionality whether SVG or canvas.
I tried with canvas but can't delete a specific part of the image with transparency.
I tried with the SVG example where I can delete a specific path that was also achievable.
can you help me to find the solution in the canvas of eraser functionality?

Comment: Not actually true at all. You can do the conversion. this guys fiddle is proof of it : https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/XbxvNj

Comment: @0xD1x0n If you'd read how that script works, and you read what my answer says, you'd see that they do not disagree.